# How do you use the MySQL Connector/C++ and XDevAPI while using XAMPP to run MySQL?

Tags: c++, mysql, xampp, mysql-x-devapi

I am trying to access a MySQL database in my C++ code. I have a feeling I may have messed something up along the way, so I'll outline what steps I took and my setup:

- I installed MySQL Connector/C++
- I installed MySQL XDevAPI
- I installed XAMPP and set it up to run a MySQL server
- I created a database with some tables in phpMyAdmin
- I linked the Connector/C++ and MySQL Server libraries and includes in my C++ project
- Then I added the following code:

```
#include <mysqlx/xdevapi.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace mysqlx;

int main() {
    try {
        Session sess(33060, "user", "password");
    }
    catch (const Error & err) {
        std::cout << err << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried this with the port 33060 as I was told that was the default, and I tried it with the port 3306 as that is what it says the port is on XAMPP.

Using the first gives this error message: "CDK Error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (winsock:10061)"
Using the second gives this error message: "CDK Error: unexpected message"

One thing that I suspect may be a problem is that the MySQL Server and C++ Connector files are in my Program Files on my C drive, while XAMPP seems to have a different set of MySQL files in its installation folder on my D drive. Did I somehow end up with 2 separate installations of MySQL or is there something else going on that I fail to understand? If so how do I handle this?

Comment: What does the XAMPP Control Panel show you for MySQL?

Comment: @JohnHanley It shows a green box indicating that it's running, the PID, and the port I mentioned above (3306)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, XAMPP is now based on MariaDB and not MySQL. The MySQL X DevAPI Connectors use the X Protocol (port 33060, by default, on a MySQL server instance) which isn't available on MariaDB.

MariaDB supports the classic MySQL protocol (port 3306), but you can't use X DevAPI clients over that protocol.

So either you find a way to use MySQL 8.x server or you will need a classic protocol [connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/).

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js

Comment: Alright, well perhaps I'll just give up on XAMPP then. Any tips for how to run a MySQL server without it?

Comment: Well, I guess it depends on whether you need Apache, PHP or Perl (which are installed out-of-the-box with XAMPP). If so, I don't have any good tips. But if you just need MySQL running on Windows, here's a [guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-installation.html).

Comment: Ah, I think I figured out how to get the MySQL Workbench to work. Thank you for your help!